# PHP server refuses to set cookie (not output issue)

Tags: php, http, cookies

I'm taking a class that has me using a common server to upload my projects to. The problem is that the server refuses to run setcookie(), even though the local instance of MAMP on my laptop does it.

This script is at the beginning of the file it's part of. There are no echo statements or HTML tags preceding it.

I've tried everything. I've used output buffering, I've tried and failed to use sessions. I've even commented out the die() statements. Oddly though, a cookie test script I use runs just fine. Is there any way to get around this issue that I haven't thought of yet?

I'll look for a way to share the server's settings in the meantime.

```
<?php

$success = false;
$error = false;
$err_msg = "";

$values = array('username', 'password');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include 'connect.php';
    /*
     *  Variable introduced: $connect
     *  Close $connect at the end of the script.
     */

    //  check for existence
    foreach($values as $value) {
        if(!isset($_POST[$value])) {
            $error = true;
            $err_msg .= "{$value} is empty!<br>\n";
        }
    }

    if($error === false) {

        //  sanitize
        foreach($values as $value) {
            if(gettype($_POST[$value]) === "string") {
                //  NOTE: Reassignment of values in $_POST to sanitized output.
                $_POST[$value] = filter_var($_POST[$value], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            }
        }

        //  validate
        if( preg_match("/^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$/", $_POST['username']) == 0 ) {
            $error = true;
            $err_msg .= "Username is in the wrong format.<br>\n";
        }

        if( preg_match('/^\S{7,}$/', $_POST['password']) == 0 ) {
            $error = true;
            $err_msg .= "Password is in the wrong format.<br>\n";
        }

        if($error === false) {

            //check username existence 
            $query = "select userID from users where username = '{$_POST['username']}'";
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
            if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0 ) {
                $error = true;
                $err_msg .= "Username does not exist.<br>\n";
            }

            if($error === false){

                //Check passwords
                $query = "select count(userID) as count from users where username = '{$_POST['username']}' and passkey = '{$_POST['password']}'";
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                if(!$result){
                    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($connect));
                } elseif (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        if($row['count'] == 1){
                            $success = true;
                            $error = false;
                    /*** This is the failure point ***/
                            setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time() + 86400);
                        } else {
                            $error = true;
                            $success = false;
                            $err_msg .= "Wrong password.<br>\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($connect);
}

?>
```

Comment: try `setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], time() + 86400, '/');` . Let me know responce

Comment: There are some major security flaws in your code.

Comment: Other than the obvious implications of jerry-rigging to force an application to work, what are the other security flaws?

Answer (score 0):

Its look like you are not setting `path` param to set-cookie. In this case cookie will only set to your `current directory`.

Basic syntex to set cookie.

`setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure,httponly);`

here if path set to "/", the cookie will be available within the entire domain.
For more detail [php setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: I did that at one point. It didn't work. Plus the file this belongs to is in the website's root directory already so root = current.

Comment: well I faces the same issue but solved with upper solution.Try `print_r($_COOKIE);` after set them and also check in browser setting on different pages.